# How should I specify argument "prob" when using sample() for resampling?

Tags: r, statistics, sampling, resampling

## In short

I'm trying to better understand the argument `prob` as part of the function `sample` in R. In what follows, I both ask a question, and provide a piece of R code in connection with my question.

## Question

Suppose I have generated `10,000` random standard `rnorm`s. I then want to draw a sample of `size` `5` from this mother `10,000` standard `rnorm`s.

How should I set the `prob` argument within the `sample` such that the probability of drawing these `5` numbers from the mother `rnorm` considers that the middle areas of the mother `rnorm` are denser but tail areas are thinner (*so in drawing these 5 numbers it would draw from the denser areas more frequently than the tail areas*)?

```
x = rnorm(1e4)
sample( x = x, size = 5, replace = TRUE, prob = ? ) ## what should be "prob" here?
# OR I leave `prob` to be the default by not using it: 
sample( x = x, size = 5, replace = TRUE )
```

Comment: Because you drew from a normal distribution, it's already the case that you'd have more observations in the center of the original distribution. Therefore `sample()` it more likely to return those. What situation are you trying to simulate here? What do you want the resulting distribution to be?

Comment: @MrFlick, you're right. I was overthinking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overthinking is devil.

You want to resample these samples, following the original distribution or an empirical distribution. Think about how an empirical CDF is obtained:

```
plot(sort(x), 1:length(x)/length(x))
```

In other words, the empirical PDF is just

```
plot(sort(x), rep(1/length(x), length(x)))
```

So, we want `prob = rep(1/length(x), length(x))` or simply, `prob = rep(1, length(x))` as `sample` normalizes `prob` internally. Or, just leave it unspecified as equal probability is default.